# How can I make a border to hexagon?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, sass

I have a problem with creating a border to hexagon-shaped `<div>`.

I need to create [this structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDBdv.jpg) of hexagons (there's russian text at the image, never mind). I made both hexagons using `clip-path`:

```html
<div class="widgets__control">
     <div class="widgets__control-inner">
         Aaaaa
     </div>
</div>
```

```css
@mixin widget {
        width: 240px;
        height: 207px;
        background-color: #fff;
        clip-path: polygon(23% 0, 78% 0, 100% 50%, 78% 100%, 23% 100%, 0 50%);
    }
@mixin widgets__inner {
    width: 228px;
    height: 195px;
    text-align: center;
    clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 75% 0, 100% 57%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%);
}

.widgets__control {
        @include widget;

        position: absolute;
        top: 31px;
        left: 536px;
        text-align: center;
    }
.widgets__control-inner {
        @include widgets__inner;

        border: 2px solid #f00;
        color: #f00;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

But I couldn't make a border to inner hexagon. I get [this view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11PMG.jpg).

Then I tried to create hexagons using [this site](https://csshexagon.com/). After creation of the outer hexagon I rotated him on 30 degrees and realised that it's also a bad idea:

```html
<div class="hexagon"></div>
```

```css
.hexagon {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px; 
    height: 173.21px;
    background-color: #64C7CC;
    border: 1px solid #64C7CC;
    margin: 86.60px 30px;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
  }

  .hexagon:before,
  .hexagon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    border-left: 151px solid transparent;
    border-right: 151px solid transparent;
  }

  .hexagon:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    border-bottom: 86.60px solid #64C7CC;
  }

  .hexagon:after {
    top: 100%;
    width: 0;
    border-top: 86.60px solid #64C7CC;
  }
```

It's a bad idea because the content of hexagon is [rotating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nipjf.jpg), too.

How can I make this structure like at the image? Or maybe I can somehow add a border using `clip-path`?

Comment: You should add the relevant code here so that your question contains a [mcve].

Comment: Give this a sus: http://brenna.github.io/csshexagon/

Comment: Lol. OP, the link you posted includes an option for adding a border to a hexagon...

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Sorry, I've updated my question and added the code.

Comment: @fubar I know, but it's a bad idea in my situation (explained in updated post).